# $1 through $9 only in perl, can we go further?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a requirement to match 12 numbers in a sequence but i am getting limited to 9th number. Is there any way to go beyond 9 matches ?

my string is something like

```
{"Column5": "Null", "Column4": "Null", "Column6": "Null", "Column1": "END", "Column3": "Null", "Column2": "Null"}
```

where columns are fixed but in place of Null there can be any sequence/characters.

I tried matching columns and subsequent strings but i have 12 matches whereas i am limited till only $9.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: That looks like JSON, so why not use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily put your matches into an actual array rather than relying on `$1` and friends:

`my @matches = $some_string =~ /(some) (regex) with (m)(a)(n)(y) (c)(a)(p)(t)(u)r(e)(s)/;`

Or, as suggested in a comment, use a JSON parser if you're parsing JSON data.  It will be more reliable than a quick regex-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [Dave Sherohman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426933/1400768) about using a JSON parser, or at least use an actual array to store the matches.

Perl imposes no hard limit on the number of captures (or the limit is so high that no reasonable script would run into). [The code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117671/1400768) and [even the script in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12117599/1400768) shows that you can refer to matched text in capturing group beyond 9 as usual, i.e. group 10 with `$10`, group 100 with `$100`.

(In case anyone is confused, `$1`, `$10`, ... are variables used *outside the regex* to refer to content of the capturing group. It's not syntax for backreference (e.g. `\1`, `\10`, ... or `\g{1}`, `\g{10}`, ...), which is used in the regex to match the same text captured by the capturing groups).